# Shuffle a Struct (Beginner)

Tags: struct, shuffle

Hey i'm currently trying to create a card game in c++ but i've run into some issues. I've created my deck using a struct called CardStruct. My question first has to do with the shuffeling of a struct. I've tried to shuffle it but I keep getting repeating cards. (You can see my attempt at the end of the code).

struct CardStruct 
    {
        int value;
        char suit;
    };

```
int main()

{
srand(time(0));

CardStruct Deck[52] = { { 2, char(6) }, { 3, char(6) }, { 4, char(6) }, { 5, char(6) }, { 6, char(6) }, { 7, char(6) }, { 8, char(6) }, { 9, char(6) }, { 10, char(6) }, { 11, char(6) }, { 12, char(6) }, { 13, char(6) },{ 2, char(5) }, { 3, char(5) }, { 4, char(5) }, { 5, char(5) }, { 6, char(5) }, { 7, char(5) }, { 8, char(5) }, { 9, char(5) }, { 10, char(5) }, { 11, char(5) }, { 12, char(5) }, { 13, char(5) }, { 2, char(4) }, { 3, char(4) }, { 4, char(4) }, { 5, char(4) }, { 6, char(4) }, { 7, char(4) }, { 8, char(4) }, { 9, char(4) }, { 10, char(4) }, { 11, char(4) }, { 12, char(4) }, { 13, char(4) }, { 2, char(3) }, { 3, char(3) }, { 4, char(3) }, { 5, char(3) }, { 6, char(3) }, { 7, char(3) }, { 8, char(3) }, { 9, char(3) }, { 10, char(3) }, { 11, char(3) }, { 12, char(3) }, { 13, char(3) } };

// printCards(Deck);


for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    int index = rand() % 52;
    cout << Deck[index].value << Deck[index].suit << endl;
}
```

Comment: What does the CardStruct look like? Casting the number as a char at that step is also not what you want to do. Cast the number in your output, (char)Deck[index].suit; Also the int corresponds to an ascii value with the cast, so try (char)'A' + (char)Deck[index].suit for a A-Z value.

Comment: struct CarStruct{
int value;
char suit;
};

Comment: I think I solved the int to char problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 { 2, char(6) }
```

use

```
 { 2, 'K' }
```

K being any char you want.